# How humans think when we are in the hevean or hell ? Do we have the same thoughts or insights same as we used to be before we die?

Tags: jannah, death, game, jahannam, akhirah

I've been looking for this question's answer since I've read a lot of how heaven are pictured in many surah . I'm questioning about technologies in heaven.... Is it developed as the era we're living? i wanna do some stuff that i can't do in the earth ,sitting all day long  playing console game and eating lots of french fries and KFCs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a game lover, believe me : you will have A LOT OF GAMES there ! And you are asking about technologies ?! comparing the time travel technology with the stone age may give you a glimpse about what you will see. There will be no flight simulator in Jannah , you will be playing for real, you will be flying for real :) . In Jannah , there will be new physics .

" فيها ما لا عين رأت ، ولا أذن سمعت، و لا خطر على قلب بشر "
"In Jannah , there exists what had never been seen by an eye, what had never been heard by an ear , or what had never come to any human's imagination " as the prophet Muhammad says.

But as you pay a price to buy consoles , you have to pay for Jannah . Money ? Naaaaah . Faith , obedience to Almighty , and charity for the people . That is price. Will you pay ? :)

God bless you .

Comment: Yes brother @DrWael thank you. I'm really looking forward to go through , from now i'll buy consoles lots by doing all the stuffs you've said

Comment: God bless you, and accept you and me and all Muslims in his mercy :)

Comment: Aamin...........

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from **Surah 25 - Verse 16** in Quran is that anything we wish/desire in Heaven will be provided to us and that is for an eternity. Doesn't that sound great? But in my opinion our very best reward will be to be forgiven and accepted by The Creator.

The important thing here is to pay great attention to the **Verse 61 of Surah 56** (please read the full Surah to make full sense of it). What I understand from this verse is that in the Judgment day, when all humans (and other creations) are raised from their tombs, they will be created in a new way that is different to what we are now and according to this verse, we can't know how it will be, till we are re-created.

This is extremely important because in Heaven, we won't be the human we know as we are now. We will be in a new, totally different creation/body/form and our wishes/desires will be based on that, not based on our wishes and desires in this world. There will be similarities like eating and drinking (according to many verses) but not in the exact same way as we do now.

So, while you **may** not find console games or french fries in Heaven, what you find and desire in there will make you truly satisfied and that is what really matters.

P.S. I didn't and won't include links to Surahs or Verses because it is up to the user to read Quran in whichever language and translation they want.

Comment: Wow what an aswer! Acceptable !  Thank you @envayo

Answer (score -2):

So, there will be things when you watch you will forgot all other small stuff(like gaming). Belive me jannah is more pleasent than this world. If gaming is the most exciting thing to do on earth, then there are alot more thing which are lot exciting.

Comment: I couldn't imagine if there's thing more pleasing than playing games forever