# Can you ask Allah for anything in Jannah?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, jannah, day-of-judgement

This question is a bit odd. I have heard that when a person reaches jannah on day of judgement then they can ask Allah for whatever they want and their wish will be granted. Firstly does the level of jannah that you are on limit the amount of things you can ask for? And secondly I have been obsessed with fantasies like harry potter and pirates of the caribbean. Let's say I got to jannah and I asked Allah that I wanted to live a couple of years as the character Jack sparrow in the pirates of the caribbean movies. Will Allah Grant my wish and let me be Jack sparrow for about 50 years living in 17th century britain or does it not work like that?
I was just wondering

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: @Ali My answer to a similar question regarding the topic "Will we be given anything we want in the Heaven?" might give some insights: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/32648/17173 To summarize, we will be given anything we want, but we, right now, can't know what we will want IF we are accepted into the Heaven, because both our bodies and the environment we will be living in will be different once in the Heaven, hence our needs and desires may be different too. It's also possible that if/when you see Heaven, you may totally forget about Jack Sparrow and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You may ask for anything in Jannah. And when it comes to the levels of Jannah, It has to do more with a status rather than a limit of wishes

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yh Of course, You Can Ask allah For Anything In Jannah.He Promised His Servants That They Ain't Gonna lack Anything In Jannah.And Allah Is not Someone Who Does Not Fulfil His Promises

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. See also [answer] and consider elaborating a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe that we can wish for anything in Jannah.

> **“…there will be there all that the souls could desire, all that their eyes could delight in: and ye shall abide therein (for aye).”**
> (az-Zukhruf, 43/71).
>
> **“…therein shall ye have all that your souls shall desire; therein shall ye have all that ye ask for!”** (Fussilat, 41/31).
>
> **“…what their souls desired, in that will they dwell.”** (al-Anbiya,21/102).

Rest Allah Knows the best.